# Permissions to load assembly at runtime in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I'm currently working on a function for my website that should work like this:

- User upload an dll
- I load the dll inside another app domain (with Assembly.LoadFrom) to inspect it with reflection
- Unload the app domain and delete the .dll file

This works perfectly fine when I do it locally but when I upload it to my server I get:

```
Failed to generate files: Could not load file or assembly '/the/path' or one 
of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

So the "Operation is not supported" make me a bit curious. Is it some kind of permission that I need to set the server? Or is it something I can fix through my config? Or is it simply that my server actually don't support it at all?

The only information I can see on my Windows/IIS server is that it use .NET version 4.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some code that replicates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set project Property **Local copy = true** ,if you are loading using reflection then provide deployment Item at Class level it will work.